# Show there is no solution...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

> Show that there is no solution to $(\bf D_n − I)p = 0$ except $\bf p = 0$; where $\bf D_n$ is the matrix representing the (ﬁrst) derivative for degree $n$ polynomials and $\bf p=[c_0; c_1; c_2]$ representing $p(x)= c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2$.

I set $\bf Dn-I=0$; changed it into derivative equations and showed why $\bf Dn$ does not equal $\bf I$. Therefore, $\bf p$ must be $0$.

Can someone tell me if I'm on the right track? Or if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method isn't enough- you need to show that $D_n-I$ is invertible, and not just $D_n -I \neq 0$.

One way is to do this problem is direct computation.

$D_n(p)=c_1+2c_2x$

$I(p)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2$.

So, $(D_n-I)(p)=(c_1-c_0)+(2c_2-c_1)x-c_2x^2$. For this to be $0$ we must have $c_2=0$, $(2c_2-c_1)=0$ and $(c_1-c_0)=0$ which implies $p=0$.